# CSS background Data URI not working (Chrome)

Tags: css, data-uri

**I'm trying to embed an image into my css directly as encoded data:**

```
background:#fae url("data:image/gif;base64, 

    R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jv
    b29t/f3//Ub//ge8WSLf/rhf/3kdbW1mxsbP//
    mf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAQAA4AAARe8L1Eky
    ky67QZ1hLnjM5UUde0ECwLJoExKcppV0aCcGCm
    TIHEIUEqjgaORCMxIC6e0CcguWw6aFjsVMkkIr
    7g77ZKPJjPZqIyd7sJAgVGoEGv2xsBxqNgYPj/gAwXEQA7") 

    no-repeat;
```

**But, it fails.** What's even more weird is that embedding the data URI directly into an image tag **does** work:

You can check my example out at: **[http://jsfiddle.net/cAb2y/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/cAb2y/2/)**

**Am I doing something wrong?**

(source example: http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove all of the line breaks or spaces from the Data URI:

```
h3 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    display:block;
    border:2px red solid;
    background:#fae url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jvb29t/f3//Ub//ge8WSLf/rhf/3kdbW1mxsbP//mf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAQAA4AAARe8L1Ekyky67QZ1hLnjM5UUde0ECwLJoExKcppV0aCcGCmTIHEIUEqjgaORCMxIC6e0CcguWw6aFjsVMkkIr7g77ZKPJjPZqIyd7sJAgVGoEGv2xsBxqNgYPj/gAwXEQA7") no-repeat;
}​
```